# ASP .NET Core 2.2 MVC Pass parameter from js/html

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I need help. I have MVC application in .NET core 2.2.
I have a view with form and there is one input (type text) with event onfocusout in javascript.

In this js method onfocusout I get the input value and with c# code call API from another app and set result to ViewBag or ViewData and in js I have no problem continue with this result, but I have a problem when I call the API I need value from input, but I can´t get the input value in c# code from input or from js method.

Is there any solution for me?

Here is code for example:

```
.
.
.
<input type="text" id="input" onfocusout="OnFocusOut(this)" />

<script>

function OnFocusOut(input) {
        var value = input.value;
        @ViewBag.Value = value; //not work

        @{
                //C# code to call API, here I need input value
                @ViewBag.Result = result;
        }

        alert('@ViewBag.Result'); //no problem
}

</script>
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: please clarify your problem. You can not set value back into ViewBag because its out from server anywhere. If you want set js variable with ViewBag you can do this ... var myValue = '@ViewBag.Result';

Comment: You may misunderstand how the ViewBag works.You can't do like this.Please share your requirement more detailed and let us consider if there is any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may misunderstand how the ViewBag works.

By the time your browser gets the page, your `ViewBag` has basically gone **out of scope**. This is because your MVC application uses the `ViewBag`, but Javascript only has a scope in the web browser document (this is the HTML code that was returned to the the browser by the application, after the `ViewBag` has gone out of scope. Javascript isn't part of the MVC application, only the resulting webpage.

For easier understanding:

When the application run,suppose your `ViewBag.Value` have value "aa", the following code in the cshtml file:

```
function OnFocusOut(input) {
        var value = input.value;
        @ViewBag.Value = value; 
}
```

Will be sent to the browser as:

```
function OnFocusOut(input) {
        var value = input.value;
        "aa" = value; 
}
```

Since your browser only sees this last part, it just doesn't make sense in Javascript. In you case, will cause the syntax error.